# Are Ethereum softwares tracking me?

Tags: go-ethereum

Ever since I installed the necessary softwares to mine Ethereum, all the websites requiring passwords are asking to verify that's it's really me. Some using special code sent to email, some asking my secret question etc..

Does it mean that these Ethereum softwares are actually tracking me somehow? After all I just followed instructions which I don't know what are actually doing.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of software did you install? You said the "necessary" software,
but what is "necessary" or not is a personal view.

If you only installed official ethereum softwares, they are open source and should not track you. For example, you can find the sources of geth at this url: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum and check that there is nothing tracking you in it.

Comment: But I have to mine somehow so I must use 3rd party mining softwares, or don't I? I'm just a beginner and starting to experience with these

Comment: For example, 3rd party softwares such as ethminer*

Comment: Then you should ask ethminer if their software track you.
But ethminer is not necessary to mine (you can mine with geth). 
However, it may be necessary to pool mine efficiently (I do not know).